# Fetch Issue In Record Field

Tags: google-bigquery

My Schema is mongoid    STRING  NULLABLE
order_vfid  STRING  NULLABLE
order_storeid   STRING  NULLABLE
order_filterdate    DATETIME    NULLABLE
order_sortdate  DATETIME    NULLABLE
order_time  DATETIME    NULLABLE
order_shopify_name  STRING  NULLABLE
order_shopify_id    STRING  NULLABLE
shipping_address    RECORD  REPEATED
customer_details    RECORD  REPEATED
order_payment_status    STRING  NULLABLE
order_fulfillment_status    STRING  NULLABLE
order_status    STRING  NULLABLE
order_currency  STRING  NULLABLE
order_total_paid    FLOAT   NULLABLE
is_cod  INTEGER NULLABLE
line_items  RECORD  REPEATED
lineitem_id STRING  NULLABLE
vfsku   STRING  NULLABLE
product_shopifyid   STRING  NULLABLE
variant_shopifyid   STRING  NULLABLE
quantity    FLOAT   NULLABLE
name    STRING  NULLABLE
catalogname STRING  NULLABLE
item_total_sold_price   FLOAT   NULLABLE
discount    FLOAT   NULLABLE
confirmation_date   STRING  NULLABLE
item_vforderstatus  STRING  NULLABLE
product_status  STRING  NULLABLE
type    STRING  NULLABLE
total_shipping2 FLOAT   NULLABLE
shipping_perquantity2   FLOAT   NULLABLE
vfprodid    STRING  NULLABLE

Now I am fetching data using query and I got error. Please help me out.
My query is SELECT * FROM testdata.orders where line_items.vfsku = 'VFPQ123_VT1'

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out how to [scan for STRUCT field values that satisfy a condition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#scanning_for_struct_field_values_that_satisfy_a_condition):

```
SELECT *
FROM testdata.orders
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(line_items) WHERE vfsku = 'VFPQ123_VT1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM testdata.orders,UNNEST(line_items)
WHERE vfsku = 'VFPQ123_VT1';
```

Comment: Error Occured : Cannot access field vfsku on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<lineitem_id STRING, vfsku STRING, product_shopifyid STRING, ...>>

Comment: fixed the error.

Comment: Now it's not giving proper results. It gives all results and does not satisfy the condition also.

Comment: It will satisfy the condition for sure. What do you mean by all results? You need to add all info in the question to get the expected output. I see Sergey's code is working fine. Go ahead with that. If you want to learn more here then add extra info in question.